# Bind a tkinter event generated in a class outside of class

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I am working on a program that would move a ball around depending on joystick inputs. The GUI I am using is Tkinter.

Recently, I found a demo of a method that used Tkinter and was compatible with Pygame (Prior to this, I thought that Pygame was incompatible with Tkinter. I was psyched when I could found this.)

I defined the virtual event "LT" in the class Find_Joystick. ("LT" refers to the "LT" button on a gamepad.) When pressed, it's supposed to move the ball to the left. However, when I try to bind the event to the actual movement function, the function doesn't appear to receive the input.

Here is my code (somewhat simplified):

```
 from tkinter import *
 import pygame

 class Find_Joystick:
    def __init__(self, root):
     self.root = root

        ## initialize pygame and joystick
        pygame.init()
        if(pygame.joystick.get_count() < 1):
           # no joysticks found
           print("Please connect a joystick.\n")
           self.quit()
        else:
               # create a new joystick object from
           # ---the first joystick in the list of joysticks
           joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
           # tell pygame to record joystick events
           joystick.init()

        ## start looking for events
        self.root.after(0, self.find_events)

    def find_events(self):
        ## check everything in the queue of pygame events
        events = pygame.event.get()
        joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
        LT = joystick.get_button(6)
        for event in events:
           # event type for pressing any of the joystick buttons down
           if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
            self.root.event_generate('<<JoyFoo>>')
            if LT == 1:
                self.root.event_generate('<<LT>>')

        if event.type == pygame.JOYAXISMOTION:
            self.root.event_generate('<<JoyMove>>')
            #Move left
            if axisX < 0:
                self.root.event_generate('<<Left>>')
            #Move right
            if axisX > 0:
                self.root.event_generate('<<Right>>')
            #Move upwards
            if axisY < -0.008:
                self.root.event_generate('<<Up>>')
            #Move downwards
            if axisY > -0.008:
                self.root.event_generate('<<Down>>')

    ## return to check for more events in a moment
    self.root.after(20, self.find_events)

def main():
## Tkinter initialization
root = Tk()
app = Find_Joystick(root)

frame = Canvas(root, width=500, height = 250)
frame.pack()

ball = frame.create_oval([245, 120], [255, 130], outline = 'red', fill = 'red')



def callback(event):
    frame.focus_set()


def moveLeftFunc(event):
    frame.move(ball, -3, 0)
    print('Move left')

frame.bind('<Button-1>', callback)
frame.bind('<<LT>>', moveLeftFunc)

root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the [demo](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/tb361/demo_joystick.py) I was referring to earlier (the class is the main part I am using).

Answer (score 0):

The solution might be in the event binding.
You bind the events to the frame Canvas, and then events are generated by the root widget (`self.root.event_generate('<<LT>>')`)

It could work in the other way, the event are propagated from the widget to the parent, but not from the root to the children widgets.

Can you try with :

```
root.bind('<Button-1>', callback)
root.bind('<<LT>>', moveLeftFunc)
```

(you should also remove the line `self.root.event_generate('<<JoyFoo>>')`)

EDIT :

Here is a reproducible case without the joystick stuff:

(the *child* button propagates the event to close the window, but the event triggered by the *root* timer doesn't hit the frame binding to close)

```
from tkinter import *
import sys

def quit(*arg):
    sys.exit()  

class ChildFrame(Frame):
  def __init__(self, root):
    Frame.__init__(self, root)
    self.grid()
    button = Button(self, text="Propagate Quit", command=self.child_event)
    button.pack()

  def child_event(self):
    self.event_generate('<<Propagated>>') # triggers the root binding

root = Tk()
frame = ChildFrame(root)

def root_event(*arg):
    global root
    root.event_generate('<<NotPropagated>>') # doesn't trigger child binding
    #root.event_generate('<<Propagated>>') # triggers the root binding 

root.bind('<<Propagated>>', quit)    
frame.bind('<<NotPropagated>>', quit) 

root.after(2000, root_event) # timer to create event from root to child
root.mainloop()
```